# How to remove space between two words in the same string

Tags: c#

I have a string like this

string input = "\r\n\r\nMaster = \r\nSlave\r\nRed =\r\n Blue";

What I want is that Master = Slave, Red= Blue so that I can create a dictionary.

The method that I am trying to use is:

1) String temp= Regex.Replace(str, “/r/n/r/n”, “”);

2) String temp= str.Replace(“/r/n/r/n”, “”);

Both the methods don’t seem to give me the result that I want. I even tried removing the white space but even that didn’t work out. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You want to create a dictionary with key = "Master" and value ="Slave" ?

Comment: What are the keys/values you expect in your dictionary?

Comment: Yes... Key= Master and Value= Slave

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a string like this:

```
string Str = "Master = Slave\r\nRed = Blue";
```

And for output are you looking for something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Master", "Slave" }, { "Red", "Blue" } };
```

If so, one way to do this is to first split the string on the newline characters, then split each of those on the equals character, and then add the resulting pair to a dictionary.

For example:

```
string input = "Master = Slave\r\nRed = Blue";
string[] keyValuePairs = input.Split( '\r', '\n');
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var keyValuePair in keyValuePairs)
{
    var parts = keyValuePair.Split('=');

    if (parts.Length > 1)
    {
        dict.Add(parts[0].Trim(), parts[1].Trim());
    }
}

// Result:
// dict
// Count = 2
//     [0]: {[Master, Slave]}
//     [1]: {[Red, Blue]}
```

The code above can be shortened using some `System.Linq` extension methods:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = input
    .Split(new[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Split('='))
    .Where(parts => parts.Length > 1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());
```

---

Another way to do this, since in the comments you've mentioned the newline characters may appear anywhere, is to examine the results after splitting the input on `\r\n` and splitting the result of that on the `=` character.

If the result has two parts, we have a key and a value, so add it to the dictionary. If there's only one part, and we haven't saved a key value yet, then save it as a key. Otherwise, add the saved key and this part as the value.

For example:

```
var input = "\r\n\r\nMaster = \r\nSlave\r\nRed =\r\n Blue";

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var currentKey = "";

foreach (var item in input.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    var parts = item.Split(new[] { '=' }, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (currentKey.Length == 0)
    {
        if (parts.Length > 1 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parts[1]))
        {
            dict.Add(parts[0].Trim(), parts[1].Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            currentKey = parts[0].Trim();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(currentKey, parts.Length > 1 
            ? parts[1].Trim() 
            : parts[0].Trim());

        currentKey = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the above code I am only getting the keys not their corresponding values o/p: [Master,] [Red,]

Comment: Not if you're using my sample input. Is your input different? If so, please update your question with sample input.

Comment: I have updated the sample input, it has space above the first key value pair too

Comment: Yes before the first key value pair there is space ie \r\n

Comment: It’s a new line character (‘\r’,’\n’)

Comment: Please check now

Comment: I don't understand why you are not including the `\r\n` characters in there. I cannot copy that into visual studio for testing, and the string I think you mean works fine: `string input = "\r\nMaster = Slave\r\nRed = Blue";`

Comment: string input = "\r\n\r\nMaster = \r\nSlave\r\nRed =\r\n Blue";

Comment: Ah, I see. I think you'll have to parse the string another way if the newline characters separate both the key/value pairs and the keys from the values. Probably just walk the string and capture words, while looking for the equals sign and whitespace. But if any of the keys or values have spaces in them, like `"Final Destination = Grocery Store"`, then there would be no way (that I can think of, anyway) to know when one key value pair ends and another begins.

Comment: Is there any other way that you can suggest, since I have tried most of the methods and they don’t seem to work. Thank you.

Comment: You mean you're looking for a different way than what I just suggested in my last comment? Not off the top of my head. If you can tell me what is wrong with that suggestion, or why do you want a different way, I might be able to help.